# Is it possible to start a EC2 instance using code?

Tags: amazon-ec2, remote-desktop, remote-desktop-services, amazon-web-services

I want to use an Amazon EC2 Windows instance to do remote demos of our software for potential customers. I have the instance set up and it runs fine. When the instance is running, I know how to generate a rdp link to allow customers to remote desktop in and play with our software.

However, I don't want to leave the instance running all the time, as this costs money, and we only need it for 1-2 hour demos per week.

What would be nice, is if the customer could click something on our website, and that would send a command to the EC2 to start the instance, and then give the rdp link file to the customer.

My question: is it possibly to remotely start a EC2 instance? Or is the only way to do this to manually log into the aws site and click 'start'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/, Actions -> StartInstances.